# Debugging Docker Compose Push/ Pull: How can I print the image layer information

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My cicd fails during docker compose push / pull (most likely because of large layers)

Docker prints the currently processed layer hash - no other info.

Are there configuration options available, which print the image layer information, which are usually seen during build?
I tried `dockerd --log-level=debug` and `dockerd --debug`  without receiving the required info.